# Is making a password long a good enough security measure?

Tags: password-protection

I've been growing more concerned about security of my accounts.  I started using a unique password for each account and storing a list of those passwords in a secure location.  Usually, I go to random.org and generate a random mix of letters and numbers of 10 characters, but it would be easier to remember commonly used passwords (as well as use them if I just quickly glance at my password sheet), if the password were comprised of common words.  I know that making your password something like "bricks" would be bad since it is a dictionary word, but what if I made my password "Johnthecarpenterislayingbrickstoday".  Would that be a very strong password, resistant to brute-force guessing attempts?

Comment: Humorous and interesting.  Thanks for that.  So I'm guessing the Johnthecarpenter... password would be a good one.

Comment: (In reference to the xkcd link) I always thought you shouldn't use normal words, because they can be cracked within seconds using a dictionary attack and a decently powerful computer?

Comment: Yes, but if your password was DogTreeBuildingRed... they are common words all found in the dictionary, but how's the cracker going to know there are four of them in the password and in what order?  My understanding is that the password cracking program just tries every word in the dictionary, but doesn't start trying permutations of those words.

Answer (score 0):

I read an article recently (can't remember where now) about how we've been "trained" to
use nonsensical gibberish passwords (e.g. xsWtg0X&zuL9) that are actually easier to crack
using decryption tools and brute force guessing. Makes sense if you think about it, since
they both operate on the premise of randomly generated characters.

If you make your passwords a string of words that make sense to *you* and throw in some
oddball separator character, they are supposed to be more secure.

So while 'bricks' may not be secure, '#3brickonleft' would be.

The password to my wireless router is an entire sentence, but it has NEVER been hacked.

Conversely, my hosting VPS, which up until recently used the 'recommended' gibberish
password format, was getting hacked and having the passwords reset all the flipping time.

Cheers!

Comment: Brute force would work equally well against a "gibberish" password and a sentence one, since the process is simply mixing up combinations of characters until you find one that works. To a machine, "bricks" or "DF£^%(" are exactly the same thing: six characters. The reason why your wireless router has never been hacked is, most probably, that the number of people who may want to crack it is tiny, compared to to the one of people who may attempt to crack a VPS. Besides, with Wireless one has to be in range, which further reduces the chances.

Comment: Also, brute force doesn't generated password strings randomly, as it would be quite hard to keep track of the ones already generated (and which failed). The simplest way to implement a brute force algorithm would be to simply generate strings of a certain length and fill them with characters in a sequence, e.g. "aaaa", "aaab", "aaac", "aaad" and so on (of course, including also special characters). It may take an eternity, but this method will sure cover all possible combinations.

Comment: I was also under the impression, though, that your typically password cracking algorithm will first try the most common passwords (e.g. "password" and "abcdefg") and then move on to all the words in the dictionary.  After those options are exhausted, since they are more likely to be correct than a random string of gibberish, it will start going through combinations of characters and symbols.  A whole sentence, though, will not be cracked simply by going through common dictionary words because they're put together in an order and not standing alone.